# When is the field generated by the values of irreducible characters of $g\in G$ equal to $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{|g|})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, and $g\in G$ an element of order $n$.

Let $\chi_1,\ldots,\chi_r$ be the irreducible characters of $G$.

Are there interesting conditions on $G$ and/or $g$ such that

$$\mathbb{Q}(\chi_1(g),\chi_2(g),\ldots,\chi_r(g)) = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$$

Comment: The characters of any symmetric group are integer valued, so it doesn't hold in general.

Comment: @Watson Good point! I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @user1952009 Note that $\chi_i(g)$ is in general not a root of unity.